# SPFx React Webpart URL doesn't point to hyperlink column/url value within event item

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react

I've been tryin to copy/change an existing sample from github pnp. Goal is to add a hyperlinked "Meeting Agenda" within the card itself. The sample I've copied changed is here: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-calendar-feed

within the root, I've made changes accordingly (and I think it's all good around it) but this particular piece of the puzzle is challenging for someone is newer to javascript (and react). I can't seem to lookup the actual value of the "supportingdocument" hyperlink column within the event list that I've successfully rendered (as title and so on).

[image: sample render]

When someone clicks on the "Meeting Agenda" it should take me to the "supportingdocument" column/value, but instead it just appends {supportingdocuments} to the current sharepoint site. To be clear, that link should take the user to the provided lookup URL that was filled (optionally) to the event list.

I've tried different kinds of imports from office-ui-fabric-react and I've currently set it to "Link" type. I'm not sure how to make the function work properly for button click.

Sample of what I have right now:

```
import { ActionButton, DocumentCard, DocumentCardType, FocusZone, css, Link } from "office-ui-fabric-react";
```

...some constructs...

```
 function handleClickOnLink(ev: React.MouseEvent<unknown>) {
   window.open('{supportingdocument}');
 }
```

... some more contsructs and document cards...

```
          <div className={styles.detailsContainer}>
            <div className={styles.category} style={themeVariant && { color: subTextColor }}>{category}</div>
            <div className={styles.title} style={themeVariant && { color: textColor }}>{title}</div>
            <Link className={styles.category} style={themeVariant && { color: textColor }} onClick={handleClickOnLink} underline>Meeting Agenda</Link>
            <div className={styles.datetime} style={themeVariant && { color: subTextColor }}>{dateString}</div>
            <div className={styles.location} style={themeVariant && { color: subTextColor }}>{location}</div>
            <ActionButton
              className={styles.addToMyCalendar}
              style={themeVariant && { color: textColor }}
              iconProps={{ iconName: "AddEvent" }}
              ariaLabel={strings.AddToCalendarAriaLabel}
              onClick={_onAddToMyCalendar}
            >
              {strings.AddToCalendarButtonLabel}
            </ActionButton>
          </div>
```

'''

Comment: When you are fetching data using API call, are you getting any value in this column? What is the data type of this column, "Hyperlink or Picture"?

Comment: I’m not sure how I would check for the API call. Data type is hyperlink.

Comment: What is stored in the variable `{supportingdocument}`? You can access the hyperlink from column like: `ColumnName.Link`. Also, you cannot directly get the value in function, you have to pass the value while calling the function from render method.